# Update table based on user action

Tags: php

Im tryng to update a table based on a user action please help, When i submit the query nothng happens        if user selects edit it should update the table what Am I doing wrong?

```
if ($action == "edit"){


$edit = $_POST['edit'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


$sql=mysql_query("select * from user where id='$id'");

   while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
 {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
$id = $row['id'];
$first_name = $row['first_name'];
$last_name = $row['last_name'];
$email = $row['email'];

$result=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' WHERE id='$id'");


echo("<form name='edit' method='post' action='?action=edit'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='?action=edit'>");
echo("<table class=main cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 >");
echo("<tr><td>Name: </td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='first_name' value='$first_name'></td></tr>");
echo("<tr><td>Surname: </td><td align='right'><input type='text'  name='last_name' value='$last_name'></td></tr>");
echo("<tr><td>Email: </td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='email' value='$email'></td></tr>");
echo("<tr><td></td><td><div align='right'><input type='submit'></div></td></tr>");
echo("</table>");
     }    
         }
```

Comment: 1. where are you setting $action 2. echoing all that html is bad on the eyes

Comment: where are you getting `$id` from?

Comment: `$id` isn't set before your 1st query is run so the second one isn't running.

Comment: I Have a link link this <a href='test.php?action=edit&id=$id'>Edit</a> Then if this link is clicked it will check if $action==edit, then update the table... But its not updating

Answer (score 0):

You are updating your database with the results that you are pulling in.

You need to update the database before you select your row:

**Couple of notes:** You are not setting `id` in your form (possibly make it a hidden input). The largest problem that I'm seeing is that you aren't initially setting ID (ie when there is no $_POST data).

Additionallly, you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

```
if($_POST){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $edit = $_POST['edit'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' WHERE id='$id'");
}

$sql=mysql_query("select * from user where id='$id'");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){                                             
    $id = $row['id'];
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    $email = $row['email'];


    echo("<form name='edit' method='post' action='?action=edit'>");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='?action=edit'>");
    echo("<table class=main cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 >");
    echo("<tr><td>Name: </td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='first_name' value='$first_name'></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td>Surname: </td><td align='right'><input type='text'  name='last_name' value='$last_name'></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td>Email: </td><td align='right'><input type='text' name='email' value='$email'></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td></td><td><div align='right'><input type='submit'></div></td></tr>");
    echo("</table>");
}
```

Comment: I have an r ref which will check if $action==edit <a href='test.php?action=edit&id=$id'>Edit</a> that is why I place a if ($action == "edit"){ on top of the code...

Answer (score 0):

you should check wether the form is sent by the user

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { 
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $edit = $_POST['edit'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE user SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name',email='$email' WHERE id='$id'");
}
```

Also check your security, use mysql_real_escape_string

also you can make your checks bigger, check if submit button is pressed etc...